# React Native: How do I redirect a user after completing a form?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have two screens, `HomeScreen` and `AddScreen`. When a user clicks on a button on the `HomeScreen`, they are directed to the `AddScreen`. After a user completes the form on the `AddScreen`, I want them to return to the `HomeScreen`. I am using `react-navigation`. Here is what I have tried:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

const Add = (navigation) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress={() => {
            firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection('my-table')
              .add({
                // Some stuff
              })
              .then(() => {
                // What I tried
                navigation.navigate('Home', {screen: 'HomeScreen'}
                // have also tried
                navigation.goBack()
              })
              .catch((error) => console.log(error));
          }}
        >
          <Text>Share</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use `createStackNavigator()` so you can pop the existing screen (`AddScreen` in your case) from the stack to go back to the previous screen (`HomeScreen`); you also have the option to go to n-th previous screen not just the preceeding one.

See [this question/answer](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/697) which is almost exactly the same problem you're facing.

Comment: I am already using `createStackNavigator()` my question is. When a user clicks the button to go to the `AddThought` complete the form... after the user completes the form I want them to redirect back to the home screen. What built-in function should I use? The link you provided isn't helpful because that post is 3 years old and `react-navigation` recently made an update.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! If you look up at my example you can see that the components prop looks like this `(navigation)`. Well it should look like this `({navigation})`. This allows you to access the `goBack()` function. So you code should look something like this:

```
onPress={() => {
               // Do whatever
              })
              .then(() => navigation.goBack())
              .catch((error) => console.log(error));
          }}
```